# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 Cordova Camera plugin saving pictures in LG Phones

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, lg, mfp

I developed a IBM MobileFirst 7.1.0.00.20160801-2318 based cordova application using Cordova camera plugin (**org.apache.cordova.camera**) with the settings of `savetoPhotoAlbum: false` and still the phone saves the image to photo album.

**Camera Settings**

[image: Camera Photo Options]

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. open camera app
2. capture photo
3. Captured Image is shown (preview) with the option to cancel or accept the image.
4. Select Cancel on preview of image
5. capture photo again
6. accept the image on the preview screen
7. Notice that both the cancelled and accepted images are saved in the photo album.

**NOTE:**

This issue specifically happens in LG phones (Tested in **K3 & V20**).
Is there any work around? Or any possible way to fix this.

Please let me know, if you need any additional info.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour with a pure Cordova application?

Comment: which LG phone you are using ? what is OS version on LG phone ?

Comment: Yes @VivinK , I'm able to reproduce this issue in the pure Cordova application.

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar, Im using LG K3 & V20 phones with Android 6.0.1

Comment: @sravan, just to be sure - when you say pure Cordova application, you mean a pure Cordova project , without MFP , created using Cordova CLI and not MFP Studio or MFP CLI? Please confirm. I am trying to see if LG's mod of Android is overriding the default cordova behaviour.

Comment: @VivinK, yes I created the project with Cordova CLI. I created project with the following command `cordova create hello com.test.helloWorld helloWorld`

Comment: @VivinK, Both Cordova and MFP based app with camera plugin are exhibiting the same behavior of saving images in lg devices.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this, @VivinK or @manjunathKallannavar?? Thank you

Comment: Since you mention the issue is happening in both MFP and Pure Cordova and only in LG devices, it appears there is a problem with the way Camera plugin is handled on the device. May be the ROM in LG is overriding some default behaviour.

Comment: I am using IBM MobileFirst 7.1 (fix pack - 20181219-1215) - How can I install camera plugin without using CLI, Please give me a link or suggestions how can I implement with easy way